# Сделал парсер в телегу, но не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, telegram-bot, telegram

Много раз уже обращался к этому сайту. Проблема в том, что бот должен отправлять сообщение каждый понедельник в 12:00, но в место этого в консоли пишется:

> TypeError: send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

```
import requests
import telebot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import schedule
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot("...")
authdata = {'login': '...', 'password': '...'}

session = requests.Session()
response = session.post('https://stat.system-ural.ru/', data=authdata)
parsedata = session.post('https://stat.system-ural.ru')

html = BS(parsedata.content, 'html.parser')
items = html.find_all("td", class_="utm-cell")
kot = []

for item in items:
    a = item.text
    kot.append(a)

summ = kot[7]


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ваш баланс: {summ}р")


def send_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш баланс: {summ}р')
    print('Отправлено')


schedule.every().day.at('12:08').do(send_message)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: В `send_message` у вас есть обязательный аргумент `message`, думаю понятно что он нигде не указывается в `schedule.every().day.at('12:08').do(send_message)`

Comment: Что для этого нужно прописать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант простой, если вы заранее знаете `chat_id`:

```
def send_message(chat_id: int):
    bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Ваш баланс: {summ}р')
    print('Отправлено')


schedule.every().day.at('12:08').do(lambda: send_message(<тут указываете ваш chat_id>))
```

или тоже через глобальную переменную (*я бы не советовал использовать глобальные переменные*):

```
chat_id = ...

def send_message():
    bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Ваш баланс: {summ}р')
    print('Отправлено')


schedule.every().day.at('12:08').do(send_message)
```

---

В другом случае, если `chat_id` и `summ` несколько, то нужно откуда-то брать их значения (из базы данных например), тогда можно было сделать что-то вроде:

```
def send_messages():
    for chat_id, summ in select.from.users.all():
        bot.send_message(chat_id, f'Ваш баланс: {summ}р')
    print('Отправлено')


schedule.every().day.at('12:08').do(send_messages)
```

---

**UPD.** Отправка `schedule` в отдельный поток

```
from threading import Thread

...

schedule.every().day.at('12:08').do(send_message)

def do_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

Thread(target=do_schedule).start()

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

...
```

Comment: telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 403. Description: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots

Comment: @АртемГолубев, `bot can't send messages to bots`, думаю вы что-то напутали в `chat_id`

Comment: Спасибо ,почти всё работает. Но только бот нечего не отправляет. Ошибок нет

Comment: @АртемГолубев, наверное, где-то накосячили :) Мб у вас условие какие-нибудь не выполняется... Проверяли, что код в функции send_message выполняется? Кст, у вас `bot.polling(none_stop=True)` не выполняется, т.к. цикл с `schedule.run_pending()` этому помешает (нужно в отдельный поток цикл поместить)

Comment: нет, функция не выполняется. Чтобы изменить проблему с циклом, нужно создать ещё один файл?

Comment: @АртемГолубев, не обязательно можно в этом же, но в отдельном потоке. В UPD накидал пример

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Проблема решена, как говорит програмка) (Process finished with exit code 0) Хотелось бы знать, как его теперь запустить, чтоб не завершался

Comment: Не должно само завершаться, там ведь в конце будет `bot.polling(none_stop=True)`, а это тоже бесконечный цикл :)